# Writing a pattern in java

Tags: java

2- (Display patterns) Write a method to display a pattern as follows:

```
1
2 1
3 2 1
…
n n-1 … 3 2 1
```

The method signature is `public static void displayPattern(int n)`. the user enters number for how long they want the pattern to be.

I know how to set it up but don't know what code to use inside the method. This is how far I got-

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the num for how long the pattern is");
    int n= input.nextInt();

}
public static void TheNum(int n){






}
```

Comment: Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the num for how long the pattern is");
  int n= input.nextInt();
  
 }
 public static void TheNum(int n){
  
  
  
  
  
  
 }
 

}

Comment: this is my code it got messed up

Comment: That doesn't qualify as an ***attempt***. Please try the code to print pattern first. This is a relatively simple pattern and I am sure hat you will certainly get the method to do it if you think about it for a while.

Comment: i know how to write a pattern but i dont know how to make it depending on what the user enters @JaskaranbirSingh

Comment: You are getting the int `n`. Just call the method using that? Something like: `TheNum(n);`

Comment: do u know the code @JaskaranbirSingh

Comment: @A.Smith a hint, you need to use two nested for loops. In the first for loop you loop from i=0; to i < n (the input from user) and then in the second nested loop you loop from j = i; j > 0; j-- and keep printing j after the loop finished print a new line and increment i.

Comment: yes but how would i implement the spaces @Raf

Comment: In the inner loop System.out.println(j + " ") will print a space after number.

Comment: can u show me that like in an answer form @Raf

Comment: @A.Smith see the answer. I had no intention to give you a solution, you should have done it yourself. Regardless I did so don't forget to mark it as **accepted** obviously that is optional.

Comment: Thanks although i just finished it @Raf

Comment: Glad to know you did it finally.

Comment: i did like yours but for the last System.out.println it goes like this: System.out.println("\n"); @Raf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
    for(int j=i; j > 0; j--) { 
       System.out.print(j + " "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

In the above loops. First loop goes from 0 to n times depending on value of n. Second loop is goes from value of i and keeps looping as long as j > 0.

First loop i=0 prints nothing, for i=1 j prints 1, only once then come out of loop and i become 2 and the inner loop prints 2 and 1 and then comes out of loop and prints new line and i become 3 and then inner loop print 3 and 2 and 1 and then come out of loop and so on.

Put above code in your method **TheNum** and then call your method passing it value of n that is provided by user as below:

```
TheNum(n);
```

Put above function call after the statement that takes the input.